# Authenticating to Azure SQL database without using UserID and Password

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-sql-database

I am trying to authenticate to my Azure SQL through c# using this code. The code works but I do not want to use my UserID and Password. Can I use anything else to authenticate? Token?

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace sqltest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try 
            { 
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "<server>.database.windows.net"; 
                builder.UserID = "<username>";            
                builder.Password = "<password>";     
                builder.InitialCatalog = "<database>";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery data example:");
                    Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName ");
                    sb.Append("FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc ");
                    sb.Append("JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ");
                    sb.Append("ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid;");
                    String sql = sb.ToString();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 things.
1. **Use Managed Identities for Azure Resources**
This is the recommended approach, in this method, code will generate a token using azure identities.

> **.NET Framework 4.6** or higher or **.NET Core 2.2** or
>   higher is required to use the access token method.

For More Information ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql 

2. Store sensitive information (username/password/connection string) in azure key vault

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app

Comment: What about when you want to connect code (such as an Azure Function in my tenant) to an Azure SQL database in *someone elses* Azure tenant? Has anyone developed a just-in-token-server for reading/writing data? Similar to auto-generating a short-lived, perfectly scoped, Azure Storage SAS token but instead for Azure SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL. Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-and-populate-an-azure-ad) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Managed identities is the way to accomplish this. [Here is a similar post specific to App Service to Azure SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439593/8446413) this can also be accomplished via ARM and Managed Identities can also be granted access policies to Key Vaults.